# multiple container with Traefik (reverse-proxy) solution

Tags: apache, docker, reverse-proxy, production, traefik

I want to be able to have access to multiple containers, on the same host, containing web applications. So, my host is reacheable by an ip adress, and I want, from the outside, be able to access to my container with an URL like :

```
ip_host/container1
```

To make it works, I found the [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/) solution. First, I followed the traefick [quick start](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/traefik/deploy-load-balancer).

So here my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik
        command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
         ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "8080:8080"
         - "443:443"
         volumes:
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
         - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
     php1:
         image: php:7.0-apache
         labels:
         - "traefik.backend=php1"
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:php1"
         volumes:
         - ./php1:/var/www/html
     php2:
         image: php:7.0-apache
         labels:
         - "traefik.backend=php2"
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:php2"
         volumes:
         - ./php2:/var/www/html
```

After

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I cannot curl/reach any of my containters with the following command :

```
curl -H Host:php1 http://host01
```

Did I understood well the use of Traefick? Is it just the way I build it which is not good? Do I have to put some new entries to /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
curl -H Host:php1 http://php1
```